# How to construct matrix from row/column vectors in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

Given a function/expression that yields a single column, how to build a matrix from those columns in Julia? I tried the following (simplified example):

```
column(j) = [j, j, j]      # for example
my_matrix = Float64[column(j)[i] for i in 1:3, j in 1:4]

==> 3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

The result is correct, but this is not what I want because the column-vector-expression is evaluated unnecessarily (once for every row).

I also tried this alternative approach:

```
[column(j) for j in 1:4]

==> 4-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0,1.0,1.0]
 [2.0,2.0,2.0]
 [3.0,3.0,3.0]
 [4.0,4.0,4.0]
```

But I found no way to **convert** or **reshape** this into the form I want (matrix with two dimensions instead of array of arrays).

How to achieve this in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *Julia 1.9.0* `stack` can be used to *combine a collection of arrays (or other iterable objects) of equal size into one larger array, by arranging them along one or more new dimensions* so it can be used to *construct a matrix from row/column vectors (returned from function/expression)*. For versions before 1.9.0 it can be activated with `using Compat`.

```
column(j) = [j, j, j]

stack(column(j) for j=1:4)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
```

What is fast and memory efficient.

```
using BenchmarkTools
column(j) = [j, j, j]

@btime stack(column(j) for j=1:4)
#  193.315 ns (5 allocations: 480 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime begin  #@Benoît Legat
    m = Matrix{Int}(undef, 3, 4)
    for j in 1:4
        m[:, j] = column(j)
    end
    m
end
#  201.942 ns (5 allocations: 480 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime reduce(hcat, [column(j) for j=1:4])  #@Przemyslaw Szufel
#  249.676 ns (6 allocations: 560 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten([column(j) for j in 1:4])), 3, 4)  #@Benoît Legat
#  392.325 ns (10 allocations: 976 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime Int[column(j)[i] for i in 1:3, j in 1:4]  #@radioflash
#  440.211 ns (13 allocations: 1.09 KiB)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime hcat([column(j) for j=1:4]...)  #@spencerlyon2
#  644.676 ns (10 allocations: 784 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
```

In case you have already a vector.

```
c = [[j,j,j] for j in 1:4]
#4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
# [1, 1, 1]
# [2, 2, 2]
# [3, 3, 3]
# [4, 4, 4]

stack(c)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

using BenchmarkTools

@btime stack($c)
#  63.204 ns (1 allocation: 160 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime reduce(hcat, $c)  #@Przemyslaw Szufel
#  68.758 ns (1 allocation: 160 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime begin  #@Benoît Legat
    m = Matrix{Int}(undef, 3, 4)
    for j in 1:4
        m[:, j] = $c[j]
    end
    m
end
#  75.586 ns (1 allocation: 160 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten($c)), 3, 4)  #@Benoît Legat
#  210.752 ns (5 allocations: 576 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4

@btime hcat($c...)  #@spencerlyon2
#  453.213 ns (5 allocations: 384 bytes)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks, this new function is exactly what I wanted! Benchmarks are also very interesting since basically anything with more than 5 allocations (4 columns and 1 result) is "bad". Personally, I find the rather good performance of reduce to be quite suprising, too (not sure how well these examples generalise to bigger data; SArray Columns and MMatrix result also gave a huge performance boost in my tests, but potentially only because the vectors are so small)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `hcat`?:

```
julia> column(j) = [j, j ,j]
column (generic function with 1 method)

julia> my_matrix  = hcat([column(j) for j=1:4]...)
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
```

See [hcat in Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.hcat)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I knew about the *cat functions, but I didn't know about the array => unpacked tuple conversion via ellipsis. Advice for other Julia newbies: At least consider looking at the latest version of the docs (even if using an older version of Julia), there are some drastic general improvements (e.g. THIS).

Comment: Great, glad it works for you. Yes, the manual changes quite rapidly so looking at the latest version is often a good idea.

Comment: What if the second dimension is large? I get segfaults or stackoverflows when `j` runs to values larger than 2 millions, or so.

Answer (score 4):

> But I found no way to **convert** or **reshape** this into the form I want (matrix with two dimensions instead of array of arrays).

You can obtain the matrix by reshaping the flatten'ed version of the vector of columns `c`:

```
julia> column(j) = [j, j, j]
column (generic function with 1 method)

julia> c = [column(j) for j in 1:4]
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2]
 [3, 3, 3]
 [4, 4, 4]

julia> v = collect(Iterators.flatten(c))
12-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 4
 4
 4

julia> m = reshape(v, 3, 4)
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
```

The alternative `hcat(c...)` suggested by the accepted answer works as well but as pointed out by a comment, this will not work for a large number of columns.
Indeed, if `c` is a vector of `n` columns then `hcat(c...)` will compile a method with `n` arguments. This first means that if your code does this for different number of columns then you will need to compile a new method every time. Secondly, compiling a method with too many arguments will make the stack memory overflow.

For this reason, when you don't need a one-line solution (e.g. like the one combining flatten and reshape above), it seems to me that most Julia users do:

```
m = Matrix{Int}(undef, 3, 4)
for j in 1:4
    m[:, j] = column(j)
end
```

**EDIT** @Przemyslaw suggested a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68976092/1189815

Comment: Your multiline solution does exactly what I want. It's a pity that there is nothing terse with the exact same semantics (i.e. no redundant assignments to matrix and no unnecessary evaluations of the column expression). I decided against accepting your answer because the original already solved my problem... Would give you bounty but it seems I can't.

Comment: Thanks for replying (even 6 years later). I agree that it's a pity there is no one line for that. I see the `...` in many packages so I wanted to write an alternative solution here to try to spread the word so that people realize the issue with that approach.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at answer @Benoit it is actually faster to use `reduce(hcat, c)`:

```
julia> c = [[j,j,j] for j in 1:4]
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2]
 [3, 3, 3]
 [4, 4, 4]


julia> @btime reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten($c)), 3, 4)
  232.791 ns (6 allocations: 448 bytes)
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4

julia> @btime reduce(hcat, $c)
  70.825 ns (1 allocation: 176 bytes)
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
 1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know but your solution is actually what should be done. It is [redirected to `_typed_hcat`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f2d03be48d4f6748a2d9ce87cacbb7b9ab6151ed/base/abstractarray.jl#L1624) and then [`_typed_hcat` is a specialized implementation of exactly what we want](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f2d03be48d4f6748a2d9ce87cacbb7b9ab6151ed/base/abstractarray.jl#L1562-L1594).

Comment: Somehow `reduce` is faster in surprising many use cases so it is always worth trying. Still your point about three dots `...` is supper important because it is just overused here and there degrading the performance of many libraries :-)